# Updating SameID different BatchID and Expiration

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 2 Items.

ALAXAN SameID different BatchID and Expiration...

Example:

```
BatchID 1 ItemID 1 Alaxan Quantity 10
BatchID 2 ItemID 2 Alaxan Quantity 50
```

In my program I merge the sameID now the Total of Quantity is 60....
When I buy 20pcs of Alaxan the BatchID 1 is 0 Quantity and BatchID 2 is 50pcs Alaxan that will be happen,
but in my program the BatchID 1 is -10 Quantity and Batch 2 is 60 Quantity

Anyone know how to do it ? and This is my code for Update

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand UPDATE products 
       SET Quantity Quantity SubQty 
     WHERE BatchID = ID , cn cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's totally unclear what your actual question or problem is. The only thing I recognized is that you're talking about medication.

Comment: my problem is in my inventory the ItemID 1 Alaxan will -10 Quantity and ItemID 2 Alaxan is still 60 Quantity.... it should be the ItemID 1 is 0 Quantity and ItemID is 50 Quantity

Comment: Still unclear because you didn't supply your table structure. Can you please [edit] your question and show your table properly formatted, like in [this example](http://hastebin.com/zojinuroyi.1c). It's just an example with some random table but if you could give similar details and your desired output it would be far easier for both of us.